# Which files are currently in use during rebase or merge?

Tags: git, merge

From a huge repository (a complete Operating System) I'm `rebasing` a `feature` branch on top of `master` (i.e. `git rebase master`), but there are still some merge conflits in some files.

When I resolve the conflits I have problems to build the C++ application.

Now I'm debugging to find out which block of my code is introducing bugs into the `master` branch, by resolving the merge conflits one by one.

If I try to build the application during rebasing (without resolving the merge conflits) which version of the code is being executed (`feature`'s or `master`'s)?

Comment: you will build the first commit of `feature` that introduces the conflict.

Comment: The answer tends to be "neither". The files in your working tree are a result of the failure to apply the conflicting commit. This is a mix of various files (as Tim Biegeleisen said).

Comment: Thaks @kofemann, I could understand. The files are exactly as I'm seeing in the merge tool before resolving the conflicts (a mix as you said). In my case I use VSCode as merge tool. I realized it because I saw in my build errors all of those strange characters (i.e. `<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======`) that we see during the merge conflit resolution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely look into using the `git bisect` tool for your current problem.  The tool works by going back to a certain starting commit, which is the earliest point when you believe the problem may have been introduced.  Git then uses a binary search to narrow down to the exact commit when the problem was introduced.

To your actual question, as far as I know if you are in the middle of a rebase, you will see code from a partial rebase.  This means, you will some number of your commits from the `feature` branch having been played on top of `master`.  Also, if there are any merge conflicts not yet manually resolved, then some of your source code files could still have merge markers in them, and obviously they would not even compile.

But don't go down that road, and instead learn how to use `git bisect`.

Comment: Thnaks, I'm goind to learn how to use `git bisect`

Comment: I guess the guy lacks a basic knowledge of git. He does not even know which branch or commit is checked out. Instead of learning git bisect, he should try building the repository before and after the merge, and in the branch that he has just merged.

Comment: @carnicer I did all you are saying. The question is not before or after the merge, but during merge conflicts resolution. There's a difference between merge and rebase regarding that. During merge the base is my branch and during rebase the base is master. I'd say the answer for the question would be both (like in keep both), but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: do you mean that the project builds before the merge in both merged branches? in that case: 1. it is a conflict resolution issue 2. you do not need bisect

Comment: Exactly.

I could understand now. The files are exactly as I'm seeing in the merge tool before resolving the conflicts (a mix). In my case I use VSCode as merge tool. I realized it because I saw in my build errors all of those strange characters (i.e. `<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======`) that we see during the merge conflict resolution. Thanks a lot. 

But I'm going to accept this answer to close the discussion since it introduces a new knowledge (`git bisect` use) for me. Thanks you both!

Comment: @Maf If you see conflict markers in even one source code file, then it's highly likely that your build would fail.

Comment: Yes, this is what happened, and this is precisely the answer I was looking for. Neither master nor feature, but both. Moral: The merge conflicts  should be resolved so everything can work. My initial idea was trying to test the code during the conflict resolution which is not possible because I have to resolve the conflicts so I can test.